# Double mutable borrowing in a nested loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am very new to Rust (and compiled languages more generally) and am facing some issues with the compiler and borrow checker.

#### Objective

I'm writing a function to generate a vector of all prime numbers below a given integer N, following the Sieve of Eratosthene. I am translating a Python algorithm that did the job into Rust, and have faced some challenges with types and references. After some hacky solutions to those compiler messages, I finally have a message regarding two mutable borrows, leading to E0499.

#### Code & Error

My code is as follows:

```
pub fn primes_up_to(upper_bound: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut vec: Vec<u64> = (2..=upper_bound).collect();
    for i in &vec {
        if *i != 0 {
            let lower: u64 = u64::pow(*i, 2) - 2;       
            for n in (lower..(upper_bound-1)).step_by(*i as usize) {
                vec[n as usize] = 0
            }
        }
    }
    return vec
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
Compiling sieve v1.1.0 (/mnt/exercism-iteration)
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `vec` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:10:17
   |
5  |     for i in &mut vec {
   |              --------
   |              |
   |              first mutable borrow occurs here
   |              first borrow later used here
...
10 |                 vec[n as usize] = 0
   |                 ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `sieve` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: could not compile `sieve` due to previous error
```

#### Request

I'd appreciate some explanation of the concept of borrowing (mutable/immutable) elements in a Vec, and why I'm doing it wrong here. I've looked at "The Book", but it's not clicking together.

I'm aware this code should return the full vector, and not only the non-zero prime numbers: I'm trying to get the code to run before I trim the output to what I want.